# Data structure for designing a cache with efficient insertion,deletion and the retrieval of highest value

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have to implement a cache with normal cache operations along with the facility of fast retrieval of the maximum element from the cache.

Can you please suggest data structures to implement this?

I was thinking of using hash map along with a list to maintain the minimum element.

Suggest other approaches with better complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

heap is great for fast retrival of max element.

Comment: +1. It can do efficient removal of inner elements, too, assuming you know where they are in the heap.

Answer (score 4):

There is a type of structure that I call exponential lookaside lists that are frequently used by OS's for keeping track of free chunks of memory.  You start with some base size N (somewhere between 8 bytes, and the page size of the OS) and then build an array (or stack) of lists:

```
[list N]
[list N*2]
[list N*4]
[list N*8]
...
```

And so on up to some maximum.  To maintain them, you just take the size of a new entry (S) and then use LOG2(S/N) as your offset into the lists array to determine which list to add the new chunk to.  When you need to release (or return) your largest chunk, your just scan from the highest sized list down until you find the first non-empty list, then scan for the largest chunk in that list.